# ASP NET MVC 3 Models cascading classes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, models

Part of my project uses Polls, and I'm using EF for Classes.
I have the Models:

**Polls.cs**

```
public class Poll
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("creation_date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Column("expiration_date")]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PollOption> Options { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PollVote> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

**PollOption.cs**

```
[Table("PollsOptions")]
public class PollOption {

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Poll")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Poll must be set.")]
    [Column("poll_id")]
    public int PollID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Option's Text cannot be empty.")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public int Votes { get; set; }


    public virtual Poll Poll { get; set; }
}
```

**PollVote.cs**

```
[Table("PollsVotes")]
public class PollVote
{

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Player", Description = "Player that voted.")]
    [Column("player_id", Order = 0)]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Option", Description = "Option voted by the Player.")]
    [Column("option_id", Order = 1)]
    public int OptionID { get; set; }


    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual PollOption Option { get; set; }

}
```

I want to use it on a view like this:
- Pass a model from a controller that contains a Poll List like this:

```
Poll[0]:
----PollTitle
----Options:
---- ----Option1 From Poll0
---- ----Option2 From Poll0
---- ----Option3 From Poll0

----Votes:
---- ----Vote1 for Option1 From User X
---- ----Vote2 for Option2 From User Y
---- ----Vote3 for Option3 From User Z

Poll[1]:
----PollTitle
----Options:
---- ----Option4 From Poll1
---- ----Option5 From Poll1
---- ----Option6 From Poll1

----Votes:
---- ----Vote1 for Option4 From User X
---- ----Vote2 for Option5 From User Y
---- ----Vote3 for Option6 From User Z
```

How do I do it!?

I hope you understand...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough an ready approach... customise as needed

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Poll>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@if (Model == null)
{
        @:No Polls to display.
}
else
{
    foreach (var poll in Model)
    {
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => poll)
    }
}
```

Display Template (views/shared/DisplayTemplates/Poll.cshtml)

(If you've not come accross these, they're mega useful.)

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Poll

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)

Options:
@foreach (var option in Model.Options)
{ 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m=> option.Text)
}

Votes:
@foreach (var vote in Model.Votes)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m=> vote.Option)
}
```

Hope this helps get yo on the right path.

Comment: I didn't understand this DisplayTemplates thing, can you help me?

Comment: Sure, this post is a bit old, and the examples are based on MVC2 and the webforms engine (rather than razor) but it's still valid.  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to have Model that contains all of it.
I mean, the Poll Model contains a Title (model) and also a List<Votes> (model).
And then in the view I just use it simple as a Property.


Is this possible ?

I want the Model Poll to relationate all of its properties.

I don't want to use a separate view or something like that.

Comment: That's what this does, the displayfor template is just a way of telling MVC how to render out the model when called (and they're reusable) the answer I gave, you could refactor out the whole thing to one poll displayfor template if you wanted.